# The period last quarter - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's assume I have the below dataset in postgresql. I'm interested in 8/16/2020. How can I extract the date as of 6/16/2020, being the last month of Quarter 2?

I was thinking that maybe logic-wise, it would be to get the quarter from the date, extract month number in a quarter, then, use something like where date is equal to quarter of current  date - 1. But then, how can I find the same date as of the same month number in a quarter?

[image]

Comment: You question is not clear. What I understood you want max date of Q2 from the data set?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! No, I need the date one quarter ago. I wish there is something like 'interval 1 quarter'

Comment: Can you elaborate? how you want to calculate with better example.

Comment: For example, if I use where date:: DATE = timestamp 'yesterday', I will get the values as of yesterday. What I want is to have something like 'date:: DATE = date:: DATE = timestamp 'yesterday' - INTERVAL '1 quarter' so that I get the values as of the same day one quarter ago.

Comment: Then you can use `3 month` instead of  `1 quarter`. Means use `date:: DATE = timestamp 'yesterday' - INTERVAL '3 month'`

Comment: Seriously, I have not thought of it. Feel ashamed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `3 month` instead of `1 quarter`.

```
date:: DATE = timestamp 'yesterday' - INTERVAL '3 month'
```